# Procedure of PRESS statistic

Tags: regression, algorithms, diagnostic

It is not very clear for me the calculation steps of PRESS statistic. What I have found:

1)we set aside the $j_{th}$ observation $⟨x_j,y_j⟩$ from the training set(It means, that we just remove the point $j$ from our model)

2)we use the remaining $N−1$ observations to estimate the linear regression coefficients $β^{−j}$ (So we calculate the regression without removed point)

3)we use $β^{−j}$  to predict the target in $x_j$(Not clear what does it mean?)

4) $e^{loo}_j=y_j− \hat y^{-j}$, where loo means leave-one-out

Can you please explain what we are doing in step 3 and 4? It's not very clear for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- in step 3 you predict the observation you left out using the model you fitted to the rest of the data (which you got back at step 2)
- in step 4 you calculate the prediction error (the omitted observation minus the prediction for it you made in step 3).

(You would then sum the squares of the prediction error)

In practice in regression you don't need to actually do the steps of omission and re-fitting and prediction, since you can calculate the PRESS from the fit to the complete data.